# Scraping with Selenium returning empty values after first elements

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, classname

I'm scraping a webpage and for some reason it returns correctly the first 12 elements and not the remaining 24, for a total of 36 shown in the page.

```
search_names = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('offerList-item-description-title')
names = []
for name in search_names:
    names.append(name.text)
```

search_names has a length of 36, but it returns the following (Sample):

```
[1 , 2, 3 , 4 , 5 , 6 , 7 , 8 , 9 , 10 , 11 , 12 , '', '', ... , '']
```

Any idea on why this might be happening?

Here's a snippet of the source code:
[image: Source Code Sample]

Comment: Please mention webpage link

Comment: https://www.idealo.es/cat/8694/perfumes-de-hombre.html?q=lalique

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To extract the texts from all of the elements with *class* as **offerList-item-description-title** using [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) and [python](/questions/tagged/python) you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for `visibility_of_all_elements_located()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CLASS_NAME`:

  ```
  print([my_elem.text for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "offerList-item-description-title")))])
  ```
- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  print([my_elem.text for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.offerList-item-description-title")))])
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  print([my_elem.text for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='offerList-item-description-title']")))])
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I'm getting this error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
    print([my_elem.get_attribute("innerHTML") for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "offerList-item-description-title")))])
  File "D:\Programas\Python\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:

Comment: I have changed `get_attribute("innerHTML")` to `.text`. Please retest with xpath and css and let me know the status.

Comment: Got it working DebanjanB. Thank you so much! Would you recommend always using this method for storing elements in a list? Or just in case of invisible elements?

Comment: @FoxWox Ideally you will have to keep the webdriver instance and the browser instance always in sync to perform activities using Selenium. Hence you need to induce proper type of [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52603847/how-to-sleep-webdriver-in-python-for-milliseconds/52607451#52607451)